# Throw a dice 5 times. what is the probability that you get 4 or 6 in two throws, and 1 or 3 in 3 throws. combinations like 13461 are included.

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

Now normally, I have 8 (111,113,133,131,311,331,333,313) combinations along with 3 ways to obtain it(4 4, 4 6, 6 6) , so 3/24 would be the answer according to my logic, but I am not sure that this is correct. I could really use some help.

Answer (score 0):

Usually statements like "probability that you get a ____" mean "get *at least* one ___", so that is the interpretation I will adopt.
Let $A = \{\text{At least a 4 or a 6 in first 2}\}$ and $B = \{\text{at least 1 or 3 in last 3}\}$. Then
$\bar A = \{\text{ No 4 and no 6 in first two}\}$ and $\bar B = \{\text{No 1 and no 3 in last 3}\}$, and
\begin{align*}
P(AB) &= 1 - P(\bar A\cup \bar B)\\
&= 1- [P(\bar A)+P(\bar B)-P(\bar A \bar B)]\tag 1\\
&= 1- [P(\bar A)+P(\bar B)-P(\bar A)P(\bar B)]\tag 2\\
&=1-\left[\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^2+\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^3-\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^2\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^3\right]\\
&=0.3909465
\end{align*} 
where in $(1)$ I invoke inclusion exclusion, and in $(2)$ I recognize independence.

---

If you want $A = \{\text{4 or 6 in two}\}, B = \{\text{1 or 3 in three}\}$, then 
$\bar A = \{\text{No 4 or 6 in two}\}, \bar  B = \{\text{1 or 3 in three}\}$, and
\begin{align*}
P(A B)&= P(A)P(B)\tag 1\\
&=[1-P(\bar A)][1-P(\bar B)]\\
&=\left[1-\binom{2}{0}\left(\frac{2}{6}\right)^0\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^2\right]\left[1-\binom{3}{0}\left(\frac{2}{6}\right)^0\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^3\right]\tag 2\\
&= 0.3909465
\end{align*}
where $(1)$ is true by independence and in $(2)$ I recognize the binomial distribution.

Comment: But you get a probability of almost 40%, which is not very likely I think. I mean I would expect this to have a smaller probability than 40%.

Comment: @user3602479 How about now?

Comment: It looks better now.

Comment: It might be useful to edit your OP to clarify what kinds of sequences qualify and which don't.  Does $14523$ qualify?  Does $46331$ qualify?

Comment: you can only have 4 6 or 1 or 3, so the first one doesn't, 46331 does, and so does 14631 for example. The only important thing is that you get 4 or 6 in two throws, and 1 or 3 in the remaining, but 1 could be first, and 4 could first two, doesn't matter. What do you recon of this, does the solution need tweaking?

Comment: @probablyme you there?

Comment: @user3602479 Yes, I'm back, give me a moment.

Comment: @user3602479 Actually, can you clarify "you can only have 4 6 or 1 or 3, so the first one doesn't, 46331 does, and so does 14631 for example"?

Comment: well you should, out of 5 throws get 4 or 6 in 2 throws, and 1 or 3 in 3 throws. combinations like: 34341, 13346, 64331, 34361 are all valid in this case.

Comment: @probablyme I always forget to tag.

Comment: @user3602479 You don't have to tag when it is the person who posted you are trying to reach. Anyway, I calculated it again, and I got the same thing as before. Again, I take "4 or 6" to mean "at least a 4 or 6". That is why I am getting the same thing. It is a different problem if you are asking for **exactly** one 4 or 6. And it appears that this is not the case correct?